# Determining time with AM and PM

Tags: python, datetime

I have been tasked with finding the time difference between two times. The first is the "current time" as defined by the variables and the second a "deadline" also defined by variables.

Getting the code to return the variables in the time formats I want is fine, however there are two variables, one for each side. The string form of "AM"and "PM".

```
current_hour = 12
current_minute = 37
current_section = "PM"
due_hour = 9
due_minute = 0
due_section = "PM"

import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime(2020,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(0,0,0,0,current_minute,current_hour)
current_time = (current_time.strftime("%I:%M" + current_section))
deadline = datetime.datetime(2020,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(0,0,0,0,due_minute,due_hour)
deadline = deadline.strftime("%I:%M" + due_section)

if current_time <= deadline:
    print(True)
else:
    current_time > deadline
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use f-strings to construct your datetime objects:

```
current_hour = 12
current_minute = 37
current_section = "AM"
due_hour = 12
due_minute = 0
due_section = "PM"

import datetime as dt
day = dt.date.today()

dateFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'
current = dt.datetime.strptime(f'{day.year}-{day.month}-{day.day} {current_hour}:{current_minute} {current_section}', dateFormat)
deadline = dt.datetime.strptime(f'{day.year}-{day.month}-{day.day} {due_hour}:{due_minute} {due_section}', dateFormat)

print ("Current: ", current)
print ("Deadline:", deadline)
print(current > deadline)
```

Output:

```
Current:  2020-08-27 00:37:00
Deadline: 2020-08-27 12:00:00
False
```

Comment: I have tried similar methods to this. When you change the current_section or the due_section it won't recognize it AM and PM. It tends to just measure which number is bigger.

Comment: @Jason J. Fahrenhold: What do you mean, can you can an example ?

Comment: I changed the variables of current_section and due_section to be due_section AM and current_section still as PM.I have to test all of the variables. It still runs as true.

Comment: You are right, `dateFormat` has to be: `dateFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'`

Comment: It worked perfectly. I just had to change (current > deadline) to <. Thank you so much.